# Characters changed by the webserver

Tags: javascript

I have this code in an .js file, if it is downloaded via ftp

```
texto=texto.replace(/á/g,"Waacute;");
texto=texto.replace(/é/g,"Weacute;");
texto=texto.replace(/í/g,"Wiacute;");
texto=texto.replace(/ó/g,"Woacute;");
texto=texto.replace(/ú/g,"Wuacute;");
```

but when the web browser downloads it with the webpage, that is what it gets.

```
texto=texto.replace(/Ã¡/g,"Waacute;");
texto=texto.replace(/Ã©/g,"Weacute;");
texto=texto.replace(/Ã­/g,"Wiacute;");
texto=texto.replace(/Ã³/g,"Woacute;");
texto=texto.replace(/Ãº/g,"Wuacute;");
```

I don't know what's wrong with the code. I hope some body can guide me. 
Thanks in advance.

ernesto

Comment: If you are using a text editor like notepad++ that can save the contents in multiple encodings, make sure you set the encoding to  UTF-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file is encoded in UTF8, so the `á` character is encoded as `195 161`.
The browser is interpreting the file as CP-1252, so those bytes are interpreted as two different characters

You need to add a `Content-Type` header to tell that browser that it's really UTF8:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

(Or configure your server to send that header)

Answer (score 1):

You've a UTF-8 file that's being parsed as if it was some 8-bit fixed Latin format.

Ideally, send the correct headers from the server (just how to do that depends on server and/or server-side scripting language). As a back up add `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />` though it's sucky to have it disagree with the server.

Alternatively, use unicode escapes in the javascript, and you become immune to all of this.